# Inheriting methods from a parent class

Tags: python

I have the parent method:

```
 def move(self,dx,dy):
     self.x += dx
     self.y += dy
```

which will move a ex: Point(1,1) move(2,3) -> Point(3,4)

I have a child function which needs to contain that same method, how do I call it?

Answer (score 0):

If your child class function has a different name, just use call `self.move(argx, argy)`. All methods are inherited along to be available on the instance.

If your child method has the same name (and thus overrides the parent method), you can use `super(ChildClass, self).move(argx, argy)` to call it. If you are using Python 3, you can omit the arguments to `super()` altogether and just use `super().move(argx, argy)`.

Comment: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'Point' and 'int' is the error it gives me

Comment: @andrchr: you are responsible for making sure the method still makes sense. Your subclass has assigned a `Point` class to `self.x` or `self.y`.

Comment: How would I go about changing that?

Comment: I don't know, you didn't share any code.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should look like this:

```
class A(object):
    def move(self, dx, dy):
        self.x += dx
        self.y += dy


class B(A):
    def foo(self, dx, dy):
        self.move(dx, dy)
```

Comment: That gives me an ongoing error